# How to deal with "scriptlet failure in rpm package glibc" during upgrade to Fedora 24?

Tags: fedora, package-management, upgrade, glibc, dnf

Actual message (from photo, **not** recorded in `dnf system-upgrade log -1`):

```
Upgrading   : glibc-2.23.1-18.fc24.x86_64 28/4874
warning: %trigger(cronie-1.4.12-1.fc21.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
Non-fatal <unknown> scriptlet failure in rpm package glibc
```

It *looks* like the problem is some interaction between glibc for Fedora 24 and cronie for Fedora 21. Is this a problem?

`sudo dnf reinstall glibc` worked fine, by the way.

Comment: I may be wrong, haven't used Fedora since 18.  Yet, I believe, you need to go F21->F22->F23->F24.  That's how they make the upgrade scripts.  I cannot point you to how to do it though, sorry.

Comment: Yes, the recommended ways is F21->F22->F23->F24, because there are a lot of changes between these 4 versions to keep the update scripts up-to-date for more than the latest version. Though I did 21->23 some time ago, which worked for me. Anyway, you should rather try `sudo dnf reinstall cronie`, which caries the failed scriptlet.